# How to reference another stack for file:// backend

Tags: typescript, pulumi

My objective is to organize my iac resources in familiar tiers (pulumi micro-stacks) like network, db, app, etc. As an example, I have two pulumi projects created in sibling folders using file:// backend (`pulumi login file://.`)

```
someroot/iac1
someroot/iac2
```

I want iac2 to StackReference iac1's exported values.

In iac2 code, I have tried different combinations to reference iac1.

```
let iac1 = new pulumi.StackReference("iac1");
let iac1 = new pulumi.StackReference("iac1/dev");
let iac1 = new pulumi.StackReference("../iac1/dev");
let iac1 = new pulumi.StackReference("iac1-dev");
```

Error:

```
  pulumi:pulumi:StackReference (../iac1/dev):
    error: unknown stack "../iac1/dev"
```

I think i am missing something simple. I have also tried nesting the folders.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`StackReference` needs to point at a stack not a project.
So, if you do something like:

```
pulumi stack init network-dev
pulumi up

pulumi stack init db-dev
pulumi up
```

Then in another project you can create stack references like:

```
let networkStack = new pulumi.StackReference("network-dev")
let dbStack = new pulumi.StackReference("db-dev")
```

Best practice would actually be to get the current stack programmatically (see https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/stack/#getting-the-current-stack-programmatically) and use that to construct the name of the other stacks.
The idea being that you may have a "network-dev", "network-staging", "db-dev", "db-staging", etc.